# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type') Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a very simple redux boilerplate code that works fine if I use `action?.type` and not when I use `action.type`. My understanding is that the `action` is never null right? So, any idea why I'm getting the error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')

The way I've created the project is I have an action `export const NAME_UPDATED = 'profile/updateName';` and an action creator for this action i.e. `export function updateProfile(text) { return { type: NAME_UPDATED, payload: text }}`.

My reducer is:

```
import { NAME_UPDATED } from './actions';

//initial state
const initialState = { name: 'Initial Name' }

//reducers
export function myReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action?.type) {
    case NAME_UPDATED: return { ...state, name: action.payload };
    default: return state;
  }
}
```

I'm dispatching the actions on a button press:

```
// Imports

  const myDispatch = useDispatch();
  const mySelector = useSelector(myReducer);

// Other code

        <p>
          The Current value of <code>name</code> in the store is: <code>{mySelector.name}</code>.
        </p>
        <button onClick={() => myDispatch(updateProfile('Updated Name'))}>
          Learn React
        </button>

// Other code
```

Here is the code sand box for more info: https://codesandbox.io/embed/redux-basic-example-ftrvs0?autoresize=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: `const mySelector = useSelector((store) => store)`

Comment: @Edshav useSelector is expecting a store object? I though a reducer is expected... Doing this solves it so you can add this in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`useSelector` allows you to extract data from the Redux store state, using a selector function. https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector

In your case:

```
const mySelector = useSelector((store) => store)
```